# C++ Dynamic Arrays and Pointers in Polynomial program causes exit error 255

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error, dynamic-arrays

I'm currently doing a program that read in a degree, and coefficients and creates a polynomial struct. The program can add and multiply the polynomials, then output the sum or product. The program runs, outputs the correct answer, and then gets a windows error:

poly.exe has stopped working
A problem cause the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

then scite shows an exit code: 255

I think it could be something in the double for loop I am using for the multiply poly, or with the initialization of the pointer to the array of coefficients. But I cannot figure out what. The could I am using for it is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Poly {
   int degree;
   int *coeff; //array of coefficients from lowest degree to highest degree
};

//Reads the coefficients of a polynomial from standard input
//Creates a poly struct and returns a pointer to the poly
Poly* readPoly();

//Outputs a polynomial to standard output with the variable x
void outputPoly(const Poly* p, char x);

//Computes the sum of two polynomials and returns
//a pointer to the new poly struct which is their sum
Poly* addPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b);

//Computes the product of two polynomials and returns
//a pointer to the new poly struct which is their product
Poly* multPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b);

//Returns to the heap the memory allocated for the polynomial
//and sets p to the nullptr
void deletePoly(Poly* &p);

Poly* readPoly() {
   int deg;
   //Read the highest degree
   cout << "Input the degree: ";
   cin >> deg;

   //Handles when the degree is == 0
   if(deg == 0) {
      int *C = new int[deg+1];
      Poly *p;
      p = new Poly;
      p->degree = deg;
      p->coeff = C;
      return p;
   }

   int *C = new int[deg+1];
   //Read the coefficients
   cout << "Input the coefficients: ";
   for(int i = 0; i <= deg; i++) {
      cin >> C[i];
   }

   //Create a new poly structure, assign its fields 
   //and retun a pointer to the new structure
   Poly *p;
   p = new Poly;
   p->degree = deg;
   p->coeff = C;

   return p;
}

void outputPoly(const Poly* p, char x) {
   //Set the degree and cooefficients to be used in the loop
   int d = p->degree;
   int *C = p->coeff;

   //Output the polynomial, depending on the degree/coeff
   for(int i = 0; i <= d; i++) {

      //if the coeff is zero, and the degree is > 1
      if(C[i] == 0 && i > 0)
         continue; //Skip the +

      //if the degree is 0, and the coeff is 0
      else if(i == 0 && C[i] == 0) {
         cout << C[i];
         continue; //Skip the +
      }

      //if the degree is 0, and the coeff is not 0
      else if(i == 0 && C[i] != 0)
         cout << C[i];

      //if the degree is 1, and the coeff is 0
      else if(C[i] == 0 && i == 1)
         cout << x;

      //if the degree is 1, and the coeff is 1
      else if(C[i] == 1 && i == 1)
         cout << x;

      //if the degree is 0, and the coeff is > 0
      else if(C[i] > 0 && i == 0)
         cout << C[i] << "*" << x;

      //if the coefficient is 1
      else if(C[i] == 1)
         cout << x << "^" << i;

      //if the degree is 1
      else if(i == 1)
         cout << C[i] << "*" << x;

      //any other circumstance
      else
         cout << C[i] << "*" << x << "^" << i;

      //Print a +, as long as it's not the last term
      if(i != d)
         cout << " + ";
   }
}

void deletePoly(Poly* &p) {
   delete[] p->coeff; //Delete the array first
   delete p; 
   p = nullptr;
}

const Poly* getLargest(const Poly* a, const Poly* b) {
//Helper function to get the larger polynomial, given two
   if(a->degree > b->degree)
      return a;
   else
      return b;
}

const Poly* getSmallest(const Poly* a, const Poly* b) {
//Helper function to get the smaller polynomial, given two
   if(a->degree < b->degree)
      return a;
   else
      return b;
}

Poly* addPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b){
   int i, j;

   int *polyOneC = a->coeff;
   int *polyTwoC = b->coeff;

   //The new polynomials degree is the size of the polynomial that is the largest
   int polyThreeD = getLargest(a, b)->degree;
   int *polyThreeC = new int[polyThreeD];

   for(i = 0, j = 0; j <= polyThreeD; i++, j++) {
      //If the polynomials are of different size, 
      //then any coefficent term over the size 
      //of the smaller polynomial degree stays the same
      if(i > getSmallest(a, b)->degree)
         polyThreeC[i] = getLargest(a, b)->coeff[i];
      else
         //Otherwise, just add them
         polyThreeC[i] = polyOneC[j] + polyTwoC[j];
         //"Shifts" if it's equal to zero
         if(polyThreeC[i] == 0)
            i--;
   }

   //Ensures the remaining terms have a coefficient value(0)
   while(i <= polyThreeD) {
      polyThreeC[i] = 0;
      i++;
   }

   Poly *sumPoly;
   sumPoly = new Poly;
   sumPoly->degree = polyThreeD;
   sumPoly->coeff = polyThreeC;

   return sumPoly;
}

Poly* multPoly(const Poly* a, const Poly* b) {

   //Get the degrees and arrays of coefficients
   int polyOneD = a->degree;
   int polyTwoD = b->degree; 

   int *polyOneC = a-> coeff;
   int *polyTwoC = b-> coeff;

   int polyThreeD = polyOneD + polyTwoD; 
   int *polyThreeC = new int[polyThreeD + 1];

   //Initialize the array of coefficients
   for(int i = 0; i <= polyThreeD; i++)
     polyThreeC[i] = 0;

   //Multiple the coeffients and add to the position of the degree
   for(int i = 0; i <= polyOneD; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j <= polyTwoD; j++) {
            polyThreeC[i + j] += (polyOneC[i] * polyTwoC[j]);
      }
   }

   //Create a new polynomial pointer and return it
   Poly *productPoly;
   productPoly = new Poly;
   productPoly->degree = polyThreeD;
   productPoly->coeff = polyThreeC;
   return productPoly;   
}

int main() {
   Poly *x = readPoly();
   Poly *y = readPoly();

   //Test the add poly function
   cout << "(";
   outputPoly(x, 'x');
   cout << ")";


   cout << " + ";

   cout << "(";
   outputPoly(y, 'x');
   cout << ")";
   cout << endl;

   //Call addPoly
   Poly *z = addPoly(x, y);

   cout << "= ";
   cout << "(";
   outputPoly(z, 'x');
   cout << ")";

   cout << endl;
   cout << endl;

   //Test the multiply poly function
   cout << "(";
   outputPoly(x, 'x');
   cout << ")";


   cout << " * ";

   cout << "(";
   outputPoly(y, 'x');
   cout << ")";
   cout << endl;

   //Call multPoly
   z = multPoly(x, y);

   cout << "= ";
   cout << "(";
   outputPoly(z, 'x');
   cout << ")";

   cout << endl;


   //Delete the polynomials now that we are done with them
   deletePoly(x);
   deletePoly(y);
   deletePoly(z);
}
```

one other thing is that the error doesn't occur everytime it's run, so far I've witnessed it when I enter a polynomial with a degree of say 4. As opposed to a polynomial with a degree of 2, it works fine.

Can anyone help me!

Comment: Use containers should as `std::vector` and remove all `new` from this code. You may find these errors simply disappear and good debuggers will bounds check vector making it much easier to find problems.

Comment: If you post a complete but minimal example that readers can try, you can avoid the question being closed for lacking such example.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a debugger and stepping through until the error occurs?

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell Do you have a good debugger you would recommend for Windows?

Comment: What are you using to compile with? Usually the compiler comes with one. Visual studio is very good and there are free versions available. I've also used Code::Blocks, and the debugging under that was a little worse but still good.

Comment: I use SciTe to do all of my C++ coding and compiling, it's very lightweight but as a result I don't believe it has a debugger, to my knowledge. I will check out your recommendations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocated coefficient array in addPoly (`polyThreeC`) isn't big enough.  You forgot to add one to the degree when allocating the array.

Comment: Life saver! too simple. Thank you!